# Find $d$ when $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 1 = d + \sqrt{a + b + c - d}$

Tags: polynomials

Suppose $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers such that $$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 1 = d + \sqrt{a + b + c - d}.$$ Find $d.$

---

This is one of the few problems where I'm absolutely stumped. Is there anyway to approach this problem with a simplistic solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtract $d$ from each side, then square both sides to free the second "$d$" from the radical. Then you have a quadratic equation in $d$. You could use the quadratic formula or see if the equation lends itself to something more interesting.

You will find two possible solutions, but the process might leave you with one of these not truly solving the original equation. Check by substituting each "solution" in for $d$ and see if it actually works.

Comment: Sorry for the follow-up, but I'm not sure how to get the supposed quadratic equation in $d.$ Can you help me with that?

Comment: Let $P=a^2+b^2+c^2+1$ and $Q=a+b+c$. Then $P=d+\sqrt{Q-d}$. So $P-d=\sqrt{Q-d}$. So $P^2-2Pd+d^2=Q-d$. And then $d^2+(1-2P)d+\left(P^2-Q\right)=0$.